# Drag and drop data between 2 asp table with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I need to do a planning app in asp.net C# and the drag and drop is needed to move data from one table to another table. The 2 table are dynamicaly generated in code behind. I need to be able to modify data without refreshing the page each time I drag and drop data, so I work only on the client side when I modify table.

I use draggable and droppable jquery ui function to move data between table, but when I need to take the table to export it in .xls or save it in the database it appear that the drag and drop data are not in the table even if I can see them in the table display.

So I would like to know how to add the data I drag and drop to the table and not just move the div around.

here is my javascript code:

```
$_dropEnd = null;

$(function () {
   $(".drag").draggable({
     helper: "clone",
     revert: 'invalid',
     stop: function (event, ui) {
         $(this).appendTo($_dropEnd);
         $_dropEnd = null;
     }
   });
   $(".drop").droppable({
     accept: ".drag",
     tolerance: "touch",
     drop: function (event, ui) {
         $_dropEnd = this; 
     }
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an ASP.NET control (i.e. HTML Table or ASP.NET Grid View) it's state is saved on the Server Side prior to being served to the page, any changes made to it via the Client will not be held through postback and so that is why the data doesn't appear to move.

To get around this, one option would be to use Ajax. You could send the HTML of the table to a WebService so that the data can be processed and saved.

```
$('#save').click(function() {
   // Creates an Object to store the HTML of the two tables
   var o = new Object();
   o.table1 = $('#htmlTable1-Container').html();
   o.table2 = $('#htmlTable2-Container').html();

   // Creates a JSON String for this Object
   var x = JSON.stringify(o);

   // In your Web Service create a Method that has the parameters (string table1, string table2)    

   $.ajax({
      url: "WEB SERVICE LINK",
      data:x,
      success: function() {
         // Ajax Call Successful
      },
      error: function() {
         // Ajax Call Failed
      }
   });
});
```

Another option (which is a bit awkward and not really the best idea) is to store the HTML of the table inside an ASP.NET control that enables input (i.e. A textbox), you can then retrieve this on postback and process the data on the Server Side.

```
// Stores the HTML of the two tables in Two ASP.NET Textboxes for retrieval by the Server on postback.
$('#save').click(function() {
   $('#<%= tb1.ClientID %>').val($('#htmlTable1-Container').html());
   $('#<%= tb2.ClientID %>').val($('#htmlTable2-Container').html());
});
```

Comment: So in the first case the data are save directly on the database or they pass trough AJAX, get store in the table and then AJAX send the table again?

Comment: When using the Ajax method you are sending the HTML of the tables to the Method. In this method you will have to manually parse that HTML to get the values you need to store in the database.